# how do I do case sensitive searches using evil/spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, search, replace, case-folding

I'm trying to perform a search and replace in `spacemacs` but I need it to be case sensitive when by default it appears to be case insensitive. So I try to do `:set noignorecase` but then I have this error message :

> State noignore case cannot be set as initial evil state

Any idea how to perform a case sensitive search and replace with `spacemacs`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short and narrow answer

You need to set the variable `case-fold-search` to `nil` in order
to have case sensitive search.  So: put this somewhere in your init file:

```
(setq case-fold-search nil)
```

See the manual node
on
[Searching and Case](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search-Case.html) for
more details.

#### Some background explanation

`spacemacs` relies heavily on `evil`, which emulates Vim.  In
general, you should not expect it to accept all (or even most) of
Vim's syntax.  `:set noignorecase` is straight out of Vim, but
there is no `set` command in `evil`'s limited set of `ex`
commands.

The reason you got the error messages you did is (I think) because
`evil` tries to match partially completed commands.  In browsing
through the list of `ex` commands `evil` emulates (hit `C-h v
evil-ex-commands` to see the list), the *only* command that starts
with `set` is:

```
("set-initial-state" . evil-ex-set-initial-state)
```

So, in effect, you tried to tell Emacs to set `evil`'s initial
state to `noignorecase` -- which doesn't exist, and is not at all what you intended to do.

Comment: Note that you can hit `M-c` during a search to toggle case sensitivity for that  invocation of search only.

Comment: Setting `case-fold-search` does not work when doing a search/replace via `%s/foo/bar/`

Comment: For search and replace use `(setq evil-ex-search-case nil)`.

Answer (score 1):

Dan's answer was the solution in my case. Nevertheless, I also had to set the variable as default in my init.el in order to work:

```
(setq-default case-fold-search nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change to case-insensitive search for the current search session only, `C-o` in the search minibuffer to invoke the hydra interface, and `C-c` to toggle case sensitivity.