# How to do case sensitive searches using evil's evil-search?

Tags: evil, case-folding

Unlike `isearch`, evil-search mode ignores `case-fold-search` option.

Using evil-search like this for eg:

```
(setq-default evil-search-module 'evil-search)
```

Is it possible to make evil-search case sensitive?

Comment: Looking at `evil-search` source, it looks like it follows `search-upper-case` instead

Comment: FTR, for making the `/` search case-sensitive, `case-fold-search` [_is_ the right option](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30570/how-do-i-do-case-sensitive-searches-using-evil-spacemacs?rq=1).

Comment: IIRC smart search overrides `case-fold-search` in this spesific case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### What to do

You can customize the variable `evil-ex-search-case` to tell it
what you want `evil` to do when searching.  Here's the docstring:

> `evil-ex-search-case` is a variable defined in `evil-vars.el`.
>   Its value is smart
>
> Documentation:
>
> The case behaviour of the search command.
>   Smart case means that the pattern is case sensitive if and only
>   if it contains an upper case letter, otherwise it is case
>   insensitive.
>
> You can customize this variable.

If you dig into the source code, this is the variable in question:

```el
(defcustom evil-ex-search-case 'smart
  "The case behaviour of the search command.
Smart case means that the pattern is case sensitive if and only
if it contains an upper case letter, otherwise it is case
insensitive."
  :type '(radio (const :tag "Case sensitive." sensitive)
                (const :tag "Case insensitive." insensitive)
                (const :tag "Smart case." smart))
  :group 'evil)
```

Now: you can either use the `customize` interface to choose your
option, or you could put the following in your init file:

```
(setq evil-ex-search-case 'sensitive)
```

#### Here's how I found this information.

First, I asked apropos to tell me about various functions and variables related to evil searches (`M-x apropos evil search`).  I then searched that list for mentions of "case," and checked out the variable `evil-ex-search-case`.  When that looked like the relevant variable, I followed the link in the help window to the source code to figure out what value I needed to set it to.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, I'd actually read over the source code for evil-search but found multiple terms that mention case (`evil-ex-regex-case`. `evil-ex-regex-without-case`, `evil-ex-pattern-ignore-case`)... so wasn't sure which was important to access.

Comment: This worked for me only after also going into emacs menu Options->Default Search Options, and unchecking "ignore case"

Answer (score 2):

Super old question, but for anyone looking for a more vim-like solution, try this:

```
(defun set-noic() 
  "set case sensitive" 
  (interactive) 
  (setq evil-ex-search-case 'sensitive))
(defun set-ic() 
  "set ignore case" 
  (interactive) 
  (setq evil-ex-search-case 'insensitive))
```

Then you can change case sensitivity using `:set-ic` or `:set-noic`, just like you did in vim. Just have to remember the dash.

Comment: You just taught me that interactive functions could be called via the ex command line.  I had no idea I could skip hitting **`M-x`** and just use **`:`** instead.  Thank you.